# Arch - Nginx still active running after uninstalled?

Tags: apache, nginx, archlinux

I have uninstalled nginx already. So if I try it again:

```
$ sudo pacman -Rns nginx
error: target not found: nginx
```

But it is still running on my default port when I check:

```
$ sudo systemctl status nginx
Failed to dump process list, ignoring: Unit nginx.service not found.
● nginx.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-10 04:28:41 BST; 1 weeks 3 days ago
 Main PID: 26966 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
```

Even though it says `nginx.service not found` but it is still saying that it is active:

```
Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-10 04:28:41 BST; 1 weeks 3 days ago
```

What is going on? How can I remove it completely?

Any ideas?

I am trying to install Apache. But I has an error from Apache because it says port 80 is already in use!

```
$ sudo systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - Apache Web Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-04-20 23:32:36 BST; 14s ago
  Process: 956 ExecStop=/usr/bin/httpd -k graceful-stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 954 ExecStart=/usr/bin/httpd -k start -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 954 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 20 23:32:35 localhost systemd[1]: Started Apache Web Server.
Apr 20 23:32:35 localhost httpd[954]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Apr 20 23:32:35 localhost httpd[954]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Apr 20 23:32:35 localhost httpd[954]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Apr 20 23:32:35 localhost httpd[954]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Apr 20 23:32:36 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 20 23:32:36 localhost httpd[956]: httpd (no pid file) not running
Apr 20 23:32:36 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 20 23:32:36 localhost systemd[1]: httpd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: just kill nginx: `pkill -9 nginx`

Comment: @NarūnasK thanks. I use `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp` and it seems to be OK!

Answer (score 0):

You could just stop the nginx service with `sudo systemctl stop nginx.service` or as @teelou mentioned, kill the process using port 80